# Proving that $(\exists x_i)(\forall x_j) \mathscr B \to (\forall x_j) (\exists x_i) \mathscr B$ is logically valid.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic

This question is from "Introduction to Mathmatical Logic" by Elliot Mendelson ,fourth edition, exercise 2.18.(i).

I have to show that  $(\exists x_i)(\forall x_j) \mathscr B \to (\forall x_j) (\exists x_i) \mathscr B$ is logically valid.

$\underline {My proof}$:

Lets assume a sequence $s$ satisfies $(\exists x_i)(\forall x_j) \mathscr B$

1. $s$ satisfies $(\exists x_i)(\forall x_j) \mathscr B$
2. $s$ satisfies $\lnot (\forall x_i)\lnot(\forall x_j) \mathscr B$  $[\because \exists x_i \mathscr B \equiv \lnot \forall x_i \lnot \mathscr B ]$
3. $s$ does not satisfies $ (\forall x_i)\lnot(\forall x_j) \mathscr B$
4. There exists a sequence $s'$ that is different from $s$ atmost the $i_{th}$ elements and does not satisfies $ \lnot(\forall x_j) \mathscr B$
5. There exists a sequence $s'$ that is different from $s$ atmost the $i_{th}$ elements and  satisfies $ (\forall x_j) \mathscr B$
6. There exists a sequence $s'$ that is different from $s$ atmost the $i_{th}$ elements and every $s''$ that is different from $s'$ atmost the $j_{th}$ element satisfies $ \mathscr B$
7. For every $s''$ that is different from $s$ atmost the $j_{th}$ element , there exists an sequence $s'$ that is different from $s''$ atmost the $i_{th}$ element such that $s'$ satisfies $\mathscr B$
8. For every $s''$ that is different from $s$ atmost the $j_{th}$ element , there exists an sequence $s'$ that is different from $s''$ atmost the $i_{th}$ element such that $s'$ doesn't satisfy $\lnot \mathscr B$
9. For every $s''$ that is different from $s$ atmost the $j_{th}$ element ,  $s''$  doesn't satisfy  $\forall x_i \lnot \mathscr B$
10. For every $s''$ that is different from $s$ atmost the $j_{th}$ element ,  $s''$  satisfy  $\lnot \forall x_i \lnot \mathscr B$
11. $s$ satisfies $\forall x_j \lnot \forall x_i \lnot \mathscr B$
12. $s$ satisfies $\forall x_j  \exists x_i  \mathscr B$ $[\because \exists x_i \mathscr B \equiv \lnot \forall x_i \lnot \mathscr B ]$

Therefore:

13. $s$ satisfies $(\exists x_i)(\forall x_j) \mathscr B \to (\forall x_j) (\exists x_i) \mathscr B$
14. every arbitrary $s$ in an interpretation $M$ satisfies $(\exists x_i)(\forall x_j) \mathscr B \to (\forall x_j) (\exists x_i) \mathscr B$
15. $\vDash_M$ $(\exists x_i)(\forall x_j) \mathscr B \to (\forall x_j) (\exists x_i) \mathscr B$ for a interpretation $M$
16. $\vDash_M$ $(\exists x_i)(\forall x_j) \mathscr B \to (\forall x_j) (\exists x_i) \mathscr B$ for any arbitrary interpretation $M$
17. $(\exists x_i)(\forall x_j) \mathscr B \to (\forall x_j) (\exists x_i) \mathscr B$ is vaild [end]

I am not sure if my proof is correct . I am specially skeptical of the transition from step 6 to step 7.Can someone tell me if my proof has any flaws or if it is rigorous enough?

Comment: Yes the move from step 6 to 7 is correct. It formalize the intuitive fact that if there is an object $c$ such that $B(c,d)$ holds for every $d$, then for every $d$ it is enough to chose that $c$ and $B(c,d)$ will hold.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA what about my entire proof , is it rigorous enough as a solution? And do I have to add more steps between step 6 and 7 to make it rigorous? [thanks for your response]

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA And does the proof  have any other flaws in it?

Comment: No, it works....